# How to pass dynamic date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to pass date dynamic using month and date in my query

```
         select CALLLOGDATE from Demo
          WHERE CALLLOGDATE  between '25-01-2020' and '31-1-2020'
```

I tried this way but it fails for the month having 31 days

```
      select CALLLOGDATE from Demo
      WHERE CALLLOGDATE  between cast (TO_CHAR(NOW() :: DATE-67, 'dd-Mon-yy') as date) and 
      cast (TO_CHAR(NOW() :: DATE-62, 'dd-Mon-yy') as date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `BETWEEN` use a range where the upper bound is the start of the next month:

```
select *
from demo
where CALLLOGDATE >= date '2020-01-01' 
  and CALLLOGDATE < date '2020-01-01' + interval '1 month';
```

or for the current month:

```
select *
from demo
where CALLLOGDATE >= date_trunc('month', current_date) 
  and CALLLOGDATE < date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month';
```